# finding the methodology of solving logarithmic equation

Tags: logarithms

Find the value of $\log_{3} (3^{2x}-3^x+1) = x$. How should we get the value of $x$. $x$ is equal to $0$ but problematically I can't find a way to show that.

Comment: Note that $3^{\log_{3}(3^{2x} + 3^{x} + 1)} = 3^{x}.$

Answer (score 1):

Look at $3$ raised to both sides, then you get:
$$3^{\log_3(3^{2x}-3^x+1)}=3^x$$
Which is the same as
$$3^{2x}-3^x+1=3^x$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: We can't equate the powers should we divide both sides with 3^x

Comment: @tapadianewlon You're overthinking it.:) What happens if you subtract $3^x$ from both sides?

Comment: It would be better finding the value of x

Comment: @tapadianewlon But you do. Or rather you show that there is no such $x$. Since you get that $3^{2x}+1=0$.

Comment: @tapadianewlon unless you are working with a complex valued log. In that case you get $2x=log_3(-1)$, and you get infinitely many solutions.

Comment: When I divide both sides with 3^x I get 3^x-1=3^x-1 whole divided by 3^x such that I can equate the denominators which would give me 3^x=1 so x= o

Comment: @tapadianewlon I don't understand what you are saying. If you divide both sides by $3^x$ you get $\frac{3^{2x}+3^x+1}{3^x}=\frac{3^x}{3^x}$ which simplifies to $3^x+1+\frac{1}{3^x}=1$.

Comment: Its actually -1 not +1 in lhs.so if you take 1\3^x on the rhs side after taking LCM it equals 3^x-1 whole divided with 3^x on the rhs side

Comment: @tapadianewlon I see. Missed the sign. In that case it's even easier and you don't really need to divide by the $3^x$ at all. Just consider $(3^x)^2-2\cdot 3^x+1=0$ factor into $(3^x-1)^2=0$ which gives $3^x-1=0$ and $x=\log_3(1)=0$

Comment: Is the methodology of dividing by 3^x wrong becoz I got the right answer

Comment: @tapadianewlon the methodology is not wrong per se. In this particular case it gives you the correct answer. The problem is it doesn't generalize. If you have a similar question say $\log_3(3^{2x}-4\cdot 3^x+6)=x$ dividing out using $3^x$ won't work.